# thor initialisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thor

Am I right in saying that thor runs independently of rails?

If this is the case, is there anyway out of the thor box to initialse Rails and initialise things like 'config/initializers'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct - Thor runs independently of Rails.

To include the Rails environment (same as : environment in rake) do this inside the thor task method

```
require './config/environment' # require rails environments
```